# SVG: Can I put x and y position in attributes in the style?

Tags: css, svg, safari, position, styles

I would like to include positioning `x="50%" y="50%"` in a class style. Doing this does *not* work:

```
.centre {
    x: 50%;
    y: 50%;
}
```

Is there any way to include positioning in a style?

**Edit:**

Based on the answers, `translate()` should do the job, and indeed the following snippet shows it working. That is, if you’re not using Safari.

Safari doesn’t seem to like doing this on at `text` element … ?

```css
text.centre {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: .5em;
 fill: green;
 alignment-baseline: middle;
 text-anchor:middle;
 -webkit-transform: translate(50%,50%);
 transform: translate(50%,50%);
}
```

```html
<svg x="160" y="100" width="140" height="40">
 <rect style="fill: lightgrey;" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="100"/>
 <rect style="fill: white;" y="10" x="10" width="120" height="20"/>
 <svg x="10" y="10" width="120" height="20">
  <text class="centre">Hello</text>
 </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: have to find my loading cable for the test-iphone...

Comment: Safari is the new IE. For anybody else referring to this question: % in translate refers to % of element size where x/y in % refers to viewbox dimensions and % in left/top (css) refers to parent element dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, yes, you can. If you use the `transform` css property. See the attached snippet.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}

rect {
  fill: red;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" width="200">
  <rect height="100" width="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform: translate(50%, 50%)` the first is the x the second is y. If you need to move only along one axis or another you can use `translateX(x)` or `translateY(y)`

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate the positioning of paths with transform:translate();

so try manipulating your desired path with

```
.centre{
  transform:translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

maybe you will want to use some vendor prefixes for cross-browser

```
.centre{
  -webkit-transform:translate(50%, 50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(50%, 50%);
  transform:translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

i used this to animate logo parts here: http://fire.netzgestaltung.at

specific SVG CSS Properties: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html

more tutorials (ment for animating but uses css):

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/
- https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/
- https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-create-an-animated-logo-with-svg-and-css